# Should I use _0, _1, _2... as Strings or 0, 1, 2... as Numbers for _id values of a constant list of things?

Tags: mongodb

Initially, I had documents in the form of: resources:{wood:123, coal:1, silver:5} and boxes:{wood:999, coal:20}. In this example, my server's code tests (quite efficiently) if there is enough space for the wood (and it is) and enough space for the coal (and it is) and enough space for the silver (there is not, if space is 0 I don't even include it in boxes) then all is well.

I want to shorten the _id value from wood, coal, silver to a numeric representation which in turns occupies less space, packets of information are smaller when communicating to and from the client / server, etc.

I am curious about using 0, 1, 2...as numbers for the _id or _0, _1, _2...
What are the advantages of using Number or String? Are Numbers faster for queries? (ignoring index speed).

I am adding these values manually btw :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of bytes necessary to represent an integer can be found by taking the integer and dividing by 256. The number of bytes necessary to represent a string are the number of characters in the string.

It takes only one byte to represent the numbers `87` or `202`, but it takes two and three bytes to represent the same as a string (plus one more if you use the underscore).

Integers are almost certainly what you want here. However, if you're concerned about over-the-wire size, then you might see gains by shortening your keys. Rather than using `wood`, `coal`, and `silver`, you could use `w`, `c`, and `s`, saving you 11 bytes per record pulled.

Comment: right. I wanted to put 0, 1, 2 as Strings but because you can't start with a number, I added and underscore to it. I may have wood and wool so putting the first character is unsafe :) ty for your answer.